# how to match a specific file extension in shellscript

Tags: bash, shell

I looked some other posts and learnt to match file extension in the following way but why my code is not working? Thanks.

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2 
  3 for i in `ls`
  4 do
  5     if [[ "$i" == *.txt ]]
  6     then
  7         echo "$i is .txt file"
  8     else
  9         echo "$i is NOT .txt file"
 10     fi
 11 done
```

eidt:
I realized `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/bash` are different, if you are looking at this post later, remember to check which one you are using.

Comment: Do you use bash or sh?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it misidentify .txt files as non-.txt, or vice versa, or give error messages (in which case what's the exact message), or something else?

Comment: @GordonDavisson it returns `./mkpics: 24: ./mkpics: [[: not found` it's my assignment and the prof specifies I have to use `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: @Cyrus i use `#!/bin/sh`, [[ does not work well

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason this is **No. 1**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[[ ]]` expression is only available in some shells, like bash and zsh. Some more basic shells, like dash, do no support it. I'm guessing you're running this on a recent version of Ubuntu or Debian, where /bin/sh is actually dash, and hence doesn't recognize `[[`. And actually, you shouldn't use `[[ ]]` with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang anyway, since it's unsafe to depend on a feature that the shebang doesn't request.

So, what to do about it? You'll have the `[ ]` type of test expression available, but it doesn't do pattern matching (like `*.txt`). There are a number of alternate ways to do it:

- [The `case` statement](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_case_statement) *is* available in even basic shells, and has the same pattern matching capability as `[[ = ]]`. This is the most common way to do this type of thing, especially when you have a list of different patterns to check against.
- More indirectly, you can use `${var%pattern}` to try remove `.txt` from the end of the end of the value (see "Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern" [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)), and then check to see if that changed the value:

  ```
  if [ "$i" != "${i%.txt}" ]
  ```

  More explanation: suppose `$i` is "file.txt"; then this expands to `[ "file.txt" != "file" ]`, so they're not equal, and the test (for `!=`) succeeds. On the other hand, if `$i` is "file.pdf", then it expands to `[ "file.pdf" != "file.pdf" ]`, which fails because the strings are the same.

  Other notes: when using `[ ]`, use a single equal sign for string comparison, and be sure to properly double-quote all variable references to avoid confusion. Also, if you use anything that has special meaning to the shell (like `<` or `>`), you need to quote or escape them.
- You could use the `expr` command's `:` operator to do regular expression matching. (Regular expressions are a different type of pattern from the basic wildcard or "glob" expression.) You could do this, but don't.

Comment: Or if it makes more sense, strip everything through the last `'.'` and test if what remains is `"txt"`, e.g. `if [ "${i##*.}" = "txt" ]`. Whichever is easier.

Comment: thanks a lot. `if [ "$i" != "${i%.txt}" ]` works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `ls`
do
   if [[ "$i" = *".txt" ]] ; then
       echo "$i is .txt file"
   else
       echo "$i is NOT .txt file"
   fi
done
```

Comment: it still returns `./mkpics: 24: ./mkpics: [[: not found`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop in `ls` output, and [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) implementation might vary among OS distributions.

Consider:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

for i in *

do

  if [[ "$i" == *.txt ]]

  then

    echo "$i is txt file"

  else

    echo "$i is NOT txt file"

  fi

done
```

Comment: `[[: not found`. It seems I cannot use [[ in  `#!/bin/sh`, but my assignment has to use `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`